# Can use 'NO' instead of 'NOT'?

Tags: formality

> **No** valid account number was specified

or

> valid account number was **not** specified

I think both of them are correct but which one is more common? And which one is more formal?

Comment: The second isn't grammatical (putting "A" at the start would fix this).

Comment: Adding an *A* to the second one would make both correct. 2nd one is more formal, polite.

Comment: What do you mean by "formal"? What is the context that you're using this phrase? Both of them look like error messages, in which case, formality isn't an issue.

Answer (score 4):

The first sentence is correct:

> No valid account number was specified.

The second sentence needs an indefinite article at the beginning to make it correct:

> **A** valid account number was not specified.